# Python - Is there a way to use SymPy's solve() on equations with square roots?

Tags: python, math, tkinter, sympy

Given what variables are known and unknown, as well as other contextual clues, can do simple physics calculations using Sympy and math imports.

However, I've run into a problem. I'm currently trying to program the equations for 1 dimensional motion with constant acceleration. There are 4 equations and 5 variables, and in each equation, one of four variables isn't used at all.

The equation in question is Vf <sup>2</sup> = Vo<sup>2</sup> + 2*a*x, where Vf is final velocity, Vo is initial velocity, a is acceleration, and x is displacement.

My program can solve the equation, but only if the variable to be solved for is Vf. If I try to solve for any of the other variables, python throws an error: `TypeError: can't convert expression to float`. I've written a non gui program that did the same thing before and it works. I can't figure out why this doesn't.

Code below, sorry if I've made some newbie mistake.

```
       if unusedvar1dk == 't':
            if solvefor_1dk.get() == 'vfx':
                vfx = solvefor1dk = math.sqrt((vox * vox) + 2 * ax * x)
            elif solvefor_1dk.get() == 'vox':
                vox = Symbol(solvefor_1dk.get())
                vfx = math.sqrt((vox * vox) + 2 * ax * x)
                solvefor1dk = solve(vfx - knownvfx)
            elif solvefor_1dk.get() == 'ax':
                ax = Symbol(solvefor_1dk.get())
                vfx = math.sqrt((vox * vox) + 2 * ax * x)
                solvefor1dk = solve(vfx - knownvfx)
            elif solvefor_1dk.get() == 'x':
                x = Symbol(solvefor_1dk.get())
                vfx = math.sqrt((vox * vox) + 2 * ax * x)
                solvefor1dk = solve(vfx - knownvfx)
        ttk.Label(answerframe, text=solvefor_1dk.get()).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
        ttk.Label(answerframe, text="=").grid(row=2, column=1)
        ttk.Label(answerframe, text=solvefor1dk).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)
```

Comment: Check that all your symbolic variables are declared as symbols and not accidentally overwritten. Check the types of each variable before the error is reported. Just a suggestion

Comment: Can you show the `str(vfx - knownvfx)` for the expression that gives the error?